# fan motor with capacitor

Tags: wiring, fans, motor

Hi I have a fan motor off a blast chiller which im hooking up to my still radiator. the wires are brown black and blue. 
it has to have a capacitor in line and thought it would be brown but I have tried that and it just sat their poleing.
does anyone have any experience and can point me in the right direction please

kind regards
pete

Comment: Could you provide the nameplate info , model # of the motor can be used to verify what capacitor size is needed. Have you verified the capacitor is good?

Answer (score -1):

A search for this motor type and/or chiller type may show photos of the wiring of the capacitor. Most likely, that motor or chiller is produced under various names, but technically identical.